# .htaccess код отработал но заданый url не нашло

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Этот код отрабатывает но почему-то не находит такой урл, что это может значить???

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !\.(css|js|jpg|gif)$
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Например из ссылки такого вида:

`myshop.local/?controller=category&id=3`

должно получиться:

`myshop.local/category/3`

**update**
Структура каталогов, если поможет делу:

```
myshop.local
-config
-controllers
-library
-models
-tmp
-views
-www
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, что из ссылки http://myshop.local/?controller=category&id=3
должно получиться http://myshop.local/category/3/

Comment: ключ L удали из скобок в условие 
`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]` этот ключ говорит что это последнее условие и не посылает запрос на index.php

Comment: удаление не помогла, ошибка так и появляется 
Not Found

The requested URL /category/3/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Ёкарный бабай... Сайт с помощью чего сделан/написан? Структуру папок добавьте в дано.

Comment: @borodatych Сайт сделан с помощью Smarty, Вот структура :
`myshop.local
-config
-controllers
-library
-models
-tmp
-views
-www`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
```

Замените на

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
```

Comment: и это не помогло(